# Share progress bar progress between two subs

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I have a form with a progress bar on it (ProgressBar1). Is it possible to start the progress bar in one sub and then continue updating that progress bar from another sub. The first sub copies files into a folder. The second sub opens each copied file and copies that file's reference images.

So inside the first sub I do this:

```
ProgressBar1.Value = Math.Max(Math.Min(fCount, 99), 100)
```

How would I get the progress bar to start in the next sub right where it left off in the previous sub? I'm unable to replace the '100 with a count of all files and the referenced images because in the first sub where I copy the files I don't know how many images are in each file till the second sub runs.

Comment: What are you hoping to do with your progress bar after you already set it's value to 100? (I'm assuming your PB max is also 100)

Comment: `ProgressBar` controls don't start or stop. They are simply a visual representation of a ratio. It's up to you to set that ratio when and where you need to.  The control will only display what you tell it to so if you want it to display an accurate representation of the state of a process then you need to accurately measure the state of that process first. That's what you need to worry about: how do you measure the state of what you're doing. That's what you need to spend some time thinking about.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I'll look at my file again and see how I can gather the information needed to set the max on the progress bar.